# Is there a way to disable blinking of cmd Echo command when re-echoing?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I was doing some stuff with .bat files. I also tried some things with `echo`
commands. One of them was repeatingly echoing and clearing some text. It started blinking. Is there a way to prevent that?

The code:

```
@echo off
:a
echo                                              @
echo                                             @
echo                                            @
echo                                           @
echo                                          @
cls
goto a
```

Comment: It blinks because your computer's CPU can't process it fast enough. Batch is not a good language for command line graphics.

Comment: @Krii It's not the CPU - it's the function that writes characters to the screen, which is so incredible slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's blinking because the computer is running through the script too fast that the terminal cannot refresh in time. It'll loop back to a and start again before all the text fully displays, then it also does a clear. You can prevent it by adding wait times.

Here's one that makes your code slowly display nicely:

```
@echo off
:a
echo                                              @
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1.0 >NUL
echo                                             @
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1.0 >NUL
echo                                            @
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1.0 >NUL
echo                                           @
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1.0 >NUL
echo                                          @
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1.0 >NUL
cls
goto a
```

Removing all the PINGs between the echos and only have it right after the last echo and before the cls will display them in blocks. Basically the ping forces the script to wait for 1.0 milliseconds. I tried 0.5 but it still blinked. [This is where I found the method.](http://forums.afterdawn.com/threads/slow-down-echo-in-batch-file.695079/)

[WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Delay-a-Batch-File) also has an article on how to slow down the batch file, I tried some of them but they display some text, which might not be acceptable for you. Which is why I felt ping was the best in this case. 'Sleep' doesn't work on Windows 7 though, looks like it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

there is another way for doing that, but it doesn't work with spaces:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM create a CarriageReturn:
for /f %%a in ('copy "%~f0" nul /z') do set "CR=%%a"
set "line=----------"

echo Please wait...
for /l %%i in (0,1,10) do (
  <nul set /p "x=!line:~%%i!@ !cr!"
  timeout /t 1 >nul
)
echo done.
```